# How to Manage Authentication between an Angular 4 Application and an Application (Spring Boot / security)?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jhipster

We have a problem with choosing the ideal approach to handle authentication and permissions in a distributed application:

- The backend is developed by JAVA EE (Spring Boot) / Tomcat Server The
- Frontend is developed by Angular 4 / NodeJS Server

We use the Spring Security Framework, so far we have used the 3 available options (HTTP Basic, JWT and Oauth2) while trying to adapt a code generated by the Jhipster project  , But unfortunately one remains stuck in the recovery of the information of the user who wants to authenticate.

In other words, the user enters his login and password, the server receives this information via the URL ( http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate)

By debugging at java and client side, I see that the server has recovered (Username / PWD) and it sends to the browser a token in the following form (for the case Oauth2):

{"access_token":"1b0ac85d-b4ed-463f-af3a-acbce7d28353","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"ed2f9041-7726-4939-93ba-4816503e3859","expires_in":1799,"scope":"read write"}

But after that I have to retrieve the information of this user to store them in a LocalStorage (Angular 4) and reuse them, that is why after calling the first web service quoted above, I call a second Web service :
( http://localhost:8080/auth/account)

At this time, the linked function to retrieve the database information, sends a query with username / pwd = null, which gives us a 500 message

In java application :

```
/**
 * GET /authenticate : check if the user is authenticated, and return its
 * login.
 *
 * @param request
 *            the HTTP request
 * @return the login if the user is authenticated
 */

@RequestMapping(value = ApiConstants.API_ANONYME + "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String isAuthenticated(HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.debug("REST request to check if the current user is authenticated");

    String remoteUser = request.getRemoteUser();
    return remoteUser;
}

/**
 * GET /account : get the current user.
 *
 * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the current user in
 *         body, or status 500 (Internal Server Error) if the user couldn't
 *         be returned
 */
// @GetMapping("/account")

@RequestMapping(value = ApiConstants.API_AUTH + "/account", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ResponseEntity<Utilisateur> getAccount() {

    Utilisateur userWithAuthorities = userService.getUserWithAuthorities();

    return Optional.ofNullable(userWithAuthorities)
            .map(user -> new ResponseEntity<>(new Utilisateur(), HttpStatus.OK))
            .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));
}
```

In Angular 4 application :

```
export class ConnexionBodyComponent implements OnInit {

  // model = new Login("", "");
     authenticationError: boolean;
     password: string;
     rememberMe: boolean;
     username: string;
     credentials: any;

     constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private router: Router, 
     private eventManager: EventManager, private stateStorageService: 
     StateStorageService) {

                          }

     ngOnInit() {
     }


    login() {
    this.loginService.login({
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password,
    rememberMe: this.rememberMe
    }).then(() => {
    this.authenticationError = false;
    /*if (this.router.url === '/register' || 
    (/activate/.test(this.router.url)) ||
    this.router.url === '/finishReset' || this.router.url === 
    '/requestReset') {
    this.router.navigate(['']);
    }*/

  console.log(this.authenticationError);
  this.eventManager.broadcast({
    name: 'authenticationSuccess',
    content: 'Sending Authentication Success'
  });

  // // previousState was set in the authExpiredInterceptor before being 
  redirected to login modal.
  // // since login is succesful, go to stored previousState and clear 
  previousState
  const redirect = this.stateStorageService.getUrl();
  if (redirect) {
    this.router.navigate([redirect]);
  }
  }).catch(() => {
  this.authenticationError = true;
  });
  }

  }
```

AccountService :

```
     @Injectable()
     export class AccountService  {
         constructor(private http: Http) { }

         get(): Observable<any> {
             return 
     this.http.get(LocalhostSettings.API_ENDPOINT+'/auth/account').map((res: 
     Response) => res.json());
         }

         save(account: any): Observable<Response> {
             return 
     this.http.post(LocalhostSettings.API_ENDPOINT+'/auth/account', 
     account);
         }
     }
```

auth.service.ts :

```
          @Injectable()
          export class AuthService {

              constructor(
                  private principal: Principal,
                  private stateStorageService: StateStorageService,

                  private router: Router
              ) {}

              authorize(force) {
                  const authReturn = this.principal.identity(force).then(authThen.bind(this));

                  return authReturn;

                  function authThen() {
                      const isAuthenticated = this.principal.isAuthenticated();
                      const toStateInfo = this.stateStorageService.getDestinationState().destination;

                      // an authenticated user can't access to login and register pages
                      if (isAuthenticated && (toStateInfo.name === 'register')) {
                          this.router.navigate(['']);
                          return false;
                      }

                      // recover and clear previousState after external login redirect (e.g. oauth2)
                      const fromStateInfo = this.stateStorageService.getDestinationState().from;
                      const previousState = this.stateStorageService.getPreviousState();
                      if (isAuthenticated && !fromStateInfo.name && previousState) {
                          this.stateStorageService.resetPreviousState();
                          this.router.navigate([previousState.name], { queryParams:  previousState.params  });
                          return false;
                      }

                      if (toStateInfo.data.authorities && toStateInfo.data.authorities.length > 0) {
                          return this.principal.hasAnyAuthority(toStateInfo.data.authorities).then((hasAnyAuthority) => {
                              if (!hasAnyAuthority) {
                                  if (isAuthenticated) {
                                      // user is signed in but not authorized for desired state
                                      this.router.navigate(['accessdenied']);
                                  } else {
                                      // user is not authenticated. Show the state they wanted before you
                                      // send them to the login service, so you can return them when you're done
                                      const toStateParamsInfo = this.stateStorageService.getDestinationState().params;
                                      this.stateStorageService.storePreviousState(toStateInfo.name, toStateParamsInfo);
                                      // now, send them to the signin state so they can log in
                                      this.router.navigate(['accessdenied']).then(() => {
                                          console.log('accessdenied');
                                      });
                                  }
                              }
                              return hasAnyAuthority;
                          });
                      }
                      return true;
                  }
              }
          }
```

auth-oauth2.service.ts :

```
        @Injectable()
        export class AuthServerProvider {

            constructor(
                private http: Http,
                private base64: Base64,
                private $localStorage: LocalStorageService
            ) {}

            getToken() {
                return this.$localStorage.retrieve('authenticationToken');
            }

            login(credentials): Observable<any> {
                const data = 'username=' +  encodeURIComponent(credentials.username) + '&password=' +
                    encodeURIComponent(credentials.password) + '&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&' +
                    'client_secret=my-secret-token-to-change-in-production&client_id=directinfoapp';
                const headers = new Headers ({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.base64.encode('directinfoapp' + ':' + 'my-secret-token-to-change-in-production')
                });


              /*
               {"access_token":"ff102054-2072-4c29-91a8-c8f43246a3b7","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"94b68064-98a6-49e5-9dbc-0cac34e434f3","expires_in":1799,"scope":"read write"}
               */
                console.log("headers : " + headers);
                return this.http.post(LocalhostSettings.API_ENDPOINT+'/oauth/token', data, {

                    headers
                }).map(authSuccess.bind(this));

                function authSuccess(resp) {
                    const response = resp.json();

                  console.log("authSuccess " + resp.json())
                    const expiredAt = new Date();
                    expiredAt.setSeconds(expiredAt.getSeconds() + response.expires_in);
                    response.expires_at = expiredAt.getTime();
                    this.$localStorage.store('authenticationToken', response);
                    return response;
                }
            }

            logout(): Observable<any> {
                return new Observable(observer => {
                    this.http.post('api/logout', {});
                    this.$localStorage.clear('authenticationToken');
                    observer.complete();
                });
            }
        }
```

login.service.ts

```
              @Injectable()
              export class LoginService {

                  constructor(

                      private principal: Principal,
                      private authServerProvider: AuthServerProvider
                  ) {}

                  login(credentials, callback?) {
                      const cb = callback || function() {};

                      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                          this.authServerProvider.login(credentials).subscribe((data) => {
                              this.principal.identity(true).then((account) => {
                                  // After the login the language will be changed to
                                  // the language selected by the user during his registration
                                  if (account !== null) {
                                      account.langKey;
                                  }
                                  resolve(data);
                              });
                              return cb();
                          }, (err) => {
                              this.logout();
                              reject(err);
                              return cb(err);
                          });
                      });
                  }

                  logout() {
                      this.authServerProvider.logout().subscribe();
                      this.principal.authenticate(null);
                  }
              }
```

principal.service :

```
             @Injectable()
             export class Principal {
                 private userIdentity: any;
                 private authenticated = false;
                 private authenticationState = new Subject<any>();

                 constructor(
                     private account: AccountService
                 ) {}

                 authenticate(identity) {
                     this.userIdentity = identity;
                     this.authenticated = identity !== null;
                     this.authenticationState.next(this.userIdentity);
                 }

                 hasAnyAuthority(authorities: string[]): Promise<boolean> {
                     if (!this.authenticated || !this.userIdentity || !this.userIdentity.authorities) {
                         return Promise.resolve(false);
                     }

                     for (let i = 0; i < authorities.length; i++) {
                         if (this.userIdentity.authorities.indexOf(authorities[i]) !== -1) {
                             return Promise.resolve(true);
                         }
                     }

                     return Promise.resolve(false);
                 }

                 hasAuthority(authority: string): Promise<boolean> {
                     if (!this.authenticated) {
                        return Promise.resolve(false);
                     }

                     return this.identity().then((id) => {
                         return Promise.resolve(id.authorities && id.authorities.indexOf(authority) !== -1);
                     }, () => {
                         return Promise.resolve(false);
                     });
                 }

                 identity(force?: boolean): Promise<any> {
                     if (force === true) {
                         this.userIdentity = undefined;
                     }

                     // check and see if we have retrieved the userIdentity data from the server.
                     // if we have, reuse it by immediately resolving
                     if (this.userIdentity) {
                         return Promise.resolve(this.userIdentity);
                     }

                     // retrieve the userIdentity data from the server, update the identity object, and then resolve.
                     return this.account.get().toPromise().then((account) => {
                         if (account) {
                             this.userIdentity = account;
                             this.authenticated = true;
                         } else {
                             this.userIdentity = null;
                             this.authenticated = false;
                         }
                         this.authenticationState.next(this.userIdentity);
                         return this.userIdentity;
                     }).catch((err) => {
                         this.userIdentity = null;
                         this.authenticated = false;
                         this.authenticationState.next(this.userIdentity);
                         return null;
                     });
                 }

                 isAuthenticated(): boolean {
                     return this.authenticated;
                 }

                 isIdentityResolved(): boolean {
                     return this.userIdentity !== undefined;
                 }

                 getAuthenticationState(): Observable<any> {
                     return this.authenticationState.asObservable();
                 }

                 getImageUrl(): String {
                     return this.isIdentityResolved() ? this.userIdentity.imageUrl : null;
                 }
             }
```

Any ideas how I can get this done?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is too long and not so clear. Maybe you could edit it and add a high level overview what you want to achieve (who needs OAuth2 tokens, what OAuth2 flow you use) and what you have tried. To discribe the authentication process, you could use a list of steps where each step tells what action is performed by whom and what's the outcome.

Comment: My objective is to manage the security part between an angular 4 application  and a spring boot application, and I don't know the ideal choice to do it (Ouath 2, HTTP Basic or JWT), if you have a tutorial or a link Where I can find more detail I will be grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (some of the possible scenarios):

If you want to have an external authentication, use OpenID Connect (OAuth2 extension) and its ID token. Use the OAuth2 Implicit flow, so the authentication redirect is handled by your Angular application, not its server. Then you can either use the ID token as an authentication for the backend (send the token as a request header `Authorization: Bearer tokenvalue`) or your backend can use the ID token to issue its own JWT containing any additional info you need (roles, permissions and such). You would not use OAuth2 for authorization. Your backend would use its own way to check access rights.

Another way is to implement your own authentication method (e.g. just a simple form with credentials) instead of the OpenID Connect. But the OpenID Connect gives you some advantages:

- Probably more secure than your own implementation
- You don't keep user secrets in your application
- You can use multiple authentication providers